How to display bottom sheet under bottom tab bar in react native?
I wonder how can I display bottom sheet under or same level with bottom tab? I can't find anywhere example or solution how to achieve this by clicking on a bottom tab Icon or button. We can do it easy directly from screen but what if i need to open bottom sheet clicking an button on bottom tab? I do not want to display it over bottom tab. I want to open it and display under or same level with margin of bottom tab height. Is there any possibility?
